# Using GUI apps with Xming and PuTTY on Windows

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, gtk, xming

I'm new to linux and connecting to a centOS server through PuTTY.

And I want to use GUI apps like gedit, google-chrome, etc on it.

I installed Xming on my windows 10 pc and enabled X11 forwarding in Connection -> SSH -> Auth -> X11.

And I'm getting these messages:

```
[root@root ~]# google-chrome

(google-chrome:16628): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
[root@root ~]# [0126/081426.221047:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(310)] NaCl 
helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly

[root@root ~]# gedit

(gedit:16744): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Please help, thanks.

EDIT: I checked /root, but there's no file called .Xauthority.

And I got no response from the following command:

```
[root@root ~]# echo $DISPLAY
```

Literally, nothing was returned. How can I fix this?

EDIT2: I ran xauth, and got

```
[root@root ~]# xauth
Using authority file /root/.Xauthority
```

seems I do have the .Xauthority file.

Answer (score -1):

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

after puttying to your centos server. 
then try

```
gedit
```